# How do I press play or stop on Xcode, without the mouse?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to automate xcode UI, so I would like to automate the process of pressing play and stop.

The problem is that Xcode does not support anymore applescript; so there is no way to just use automator.

Is there any way to do so? I could use xcodebuild from terminal, and then run the simulator, but I need to have Xcode UI interface open and running.

Comment: are you doing this to debug a MacOS app or an iOS app running in the simulator or on a device?

Comment: Trying to build and run the app in the simulator. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Press shift+command+R to compile and run and command+. to stop

Comment: How do I automate keystroke? Terminal has no notion of keystroke